# Extract XML attributes by id using R

Tags: r, xml, parsing

I want to extract XML attributes by `id` and store them in a `list`. The following example works but it is slow (I want to apply this code to large XML documents)

**Is there a way to perform this operation more efficiently?**

```
library(XML)

query <- "http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:xml];way[amenity=fire_station](45.7073666,4.7718134,45.8082628,4.8983774);out geom;"
resp  <- xmlParse(query)
id    <- xpathSApply(resp,"//way", xmlAttrs)
xy    <- lapply(id, function(x) { 
  t(xpathSApply(resp_xml, paste0("//way[@id=\"", x, "\"]/nd"), xmlAttrs)) # The attribute is "nd"
})

# Input
# <way id="85040904">
#   <bounds minlat="45.7787373" minlon="4.8776611" maxlat="45.7791660" maxlon="4.8783108"/>
#   <nd ref="986810237" lat="45.7791513" lon="4.8781562"/>
#   <nd ref="986813467" lat="45.7790175" lon="4.8779384"/>
# ...

# Output
# $id
#       ref         lat          lon        
# [1,] "986810237" "45.7791513" "4.8781562"
# [2,] "986813467" "45.7790175" "4.8779384"
# ...
```

Comment: Yes. Use a package: https://github.com/osmdatar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this could be faster:

```
nd <- do.call(rbind, xpathApply(resp,"//way/nd", xmlAttrs))
id <- unlist(xpathApply(resp,"//way/nd", xmlAncestors, xmlGetAttr, "id"))

df <- cbind(id,nd)
```

It collects the parent attributes from the nd nodes, and combines that with the child node data.

Comment: Way faster indeed!